# Getting deleted values via relations in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relation

I have 3 tables: `vehicles`, `drivers` and `vehicle_driver_owners`.

`drivers` table includes all the registered drivers. `vehicles` table includes all the registered vehicles. `vehicle_driver_owners` is a pivot table. It shows which drivers act as owners to a particular vehicle. (A vehicle can have multiple owners and vice-versa)

I have made relation in all the 3 models(`Vehicle`, `Driver` and `VehicleDriverOwner`)

Here's the Vehicle model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Vehicle extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    protected $table = 'vehicles';
    protected $softDelete = true;

    // EACH VEHICLE CAN BELONG TO MANY OWNERS
    public function owners(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Driver', 'vehicle_driver_owners', 'vehicle_driver_owners_vehicle_id', 'vehicle_driver_owners_driver_id');
    }
}
```

Here's the `Driver` model

```
class Driver extends Eloquent{      
    protected $table = 'drivers'

   //EACH DRIVER CAN BE OWNER OF MANY VEHICLES
    public function vehicleOwner(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Vehicle', 'vehicle_driver_owners', 'vehicle_driver_owners_driver_id', 'vehicle_driver_owners_vehicle_id');
    }
}
```

Here's the `VehicleDriverOwner` model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class VehicleDriverOwner extends Eloquent {
    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    protected $table = 'vehicle_driver_owners';
    protected $fillable = ['vehicle_driver_owners_vehicle_id', 'vehicle_driver_owners_driver_id'];
    protected $softDelete = true;       
}
```

i was trying to use the softDelete feature of laravel. A vehicle has 3 owners and i want to delete one of them. i also want to keep that entry in database. So i used softDelete feature. After deleting that particular owner, `deleted_at` column of that row in `vehicle_driver_owners` table was filled with the date.

But now i'm trying to view the owners of vehicle by using `Vehicle::find(5)->owners`. It shows that deleted owner as well

Answer (score 0):

Add whereNull('vehicle_driver_owners.deleted_at') to the function owners in Vehicle

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
class Vehicle extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    protected $table = 'vehicles';
    protected $softDelete = true;

    // EACH VEHICLE CAN BELONG TO MANY OWNERS
    public function owners(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Driver', 'vehicle_driver_owners', 'vehicle_driver_owners_vehicle_id', 'vehicle_driver_owners_driver_id')
                    ->whereNull('vehicle_driver_owners.deleted_at');
    }
}
```